# Simple INSERT Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I m looking to a way to insert into database Table T1 from T2 (append operation_

Table 1 : dbo.t1

```
col1   col2
----   -----
1       ABC
2       ABCr  
3       ABCs
4       ABCd
```

Table 2 : dbo.t2

```
col1   col2
----   -----
7       ABCe
8       ABCy
```

Now , table 1 becomes

```
col1   col2
----   -----
1       ABC
2       ABCr  
3       ABCs
4       ABCd
7       ABCe
8       ABCy
```

SQL query , I m using is:

```
select * 
into dbo.t1
from dbo.t2
```

I know it would way too simple using #temp table.

I m looking for a way so that I just append the rows from T2 to T1 and keep performance as well. The existing rows of T1 is not touch at all.

Any help would be helpful.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this answer your question?  It will insert all records from Table2 to the end of Table1 (and not touch existing records in Table1)

```
insert into Table1 (col1, col2) (select col1, col2 from Table2)
```

Comment: @Adam Why the brackets around the select?

Comment: I realize they're not needed.  This is just how I do it.  I also use "as" when I do column or table aliases for some unnecessary reason :).